# FOR OR statement in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I want to minimize my code in my template because the items i would like to display are many. The variables to output are the same and im using the same template. The details are below

i tried for or statement but the error i get is 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for item in (shoe_list or cup_list)

This is the original code

```
{% extends 'base_generic.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}


<body>

  <h1 class="titleheadline"> List of items</h1>

{% if shoe_list %}
    {% for item in shoe_list %} 
      <td>{{req.colour}}</td>
      <td>{{req.size}}</td>
      <td>{{req.price}}</td>
  {% endfor %}

{% elif cup_list %}
    {% for item in cup_list %}

      <td>{{req.colour}}</td>
      <td>{{req.size}}</td>
      <td>{{req.price}}</td>

  {% endfor %}

  {% else %}
    <p>There are none in stock.</p>
  {% endif %}

</body>      

{% endblock %}
```

The below are the changes i made which is not working

```
{% extends 'base_generic.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<body>

  <h1 class="titleheadline"> List of items</h1>

{% if shoe_list or cup_list  %}
    {% for item in (shoe_list or cup_list) %} 
      <td>{{req.colour}}</td>
      <td>{{req.size}}</td>
      <td>{{req.price}}</td>
  {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    <p>There are none in stock.</p>
  {% endif %}

</body>      

{% endblock %}
```

I expect to reduce the code to give the same result like the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to combine these lists on the server side and then loop over the one single list which contains everything in the template.

For example:

views

```
# If shoe_list and cup_list are querysets
from itertools import chain
combined_list = list(chain(shoe_list, cup_list))
```

template

```
{% for item in combined_list %} 
    <td>{{item.colour}}</td>
    <td>{{item.size}}</td> 
    <td>{{item.price}}</td>
{% else %}
    There are none in stock.
{% endfor %}
```